# Opencv Contour Error

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to find contours of my image then I want to draw contour using openCV. I'm using VS 2012 and OpenCV 2.4.5 
I wrote sample code about finding contours and drawing contours.
Bu I stacked that horrible error :)  For any help I will be appreciated

```
void MyClass::findContoursAndDraw(cv::Mat image,int b,int g,int r)
{
findContours(image,contours,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
{
    int size=cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
    if(size>500)
    {
        printf("%i \n",size);
        drawContours(originalTemp,contours,i,cv::Scalar(b,g,r),2,8);        
    }

}
```

}

```
void MyClass::findContoursAndDrawFilled(cv::Mat image,int b,int g,int r)
{
findContours(image,contours,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
{
    int size=cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
    if(size>3000)
    {
        printf("%i \n",size);
        drawContours(originalImg,contours,i,cv::Scalar(b,g,r));     
    }

}
}
```

My threshold and other necessary function works very well. But My program stacked at finding contour and drawcontour function. Says that:

```
 Unhandled exception at 0x00B3A52A (opencv_imgproc245d.dll) in OpencvTest.exe: 
 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similiar problem. But there are two implicit situations.

The first one is a Drawing issue, that I copied the way the official documentation contains to solve:

```
    findContours( src, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, 
                 CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
    // iterate through all the top-level contours,
    // draw each connected component with its own random color
    int idx = 0;
    for( ; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0] )
    {
      Scalar color( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 );
      drawContours( dst, contours, idx, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy );
    }
```

This worked for me for drawing different colors for each contour.

---

EDIT: This function "drawContours" can draw a color for a contours and all children. To understand this better, read [this](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/contours-5-hierarchy.html).

---

The second one is the iterative navigation on contours. For some unknow reason, the output "contours" from the "findContours(...)" function brings contours with 0 size or a very HIGH size (it's like a memory thrash, a really big number). I solved the way I use the contour using a condition:

```
    for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
    {
    if(contours[i].size() < 10000 && contours[i].size() > 0)
       {
       int size=cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
       if(size>3000)
          {
        printf("%i \n",size);
        drawContours(originalImg,contours,i,cv::Scalar(b,g,r));     
          }
       }
    }
```

I used the condition "if(contours[i].size() < 10000 && contours[i].size() > 0)" because when, in any case, we manipulate "contours[i]", where "contours[i].size()" is 0 or that big number, the program CRASHES. (that "10000" is arbitrary, and worked in my case).